# Create json with php from all data from the database

Tags: php, json

I want to create json which contains all orders from datebase. I tried to write this code but it returns only one order.

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders  WHERE id_user = '".$userdata['user_login']."' ORDER BY `nom` ASC ");
    if ($query)
    {
        $i = 0;


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {

    $where=$row["where"];
    $time_min=$row["time_min"];
    $time_max=$row["time_max"];
    $date1=$row["date1"];
    $date2=$row["date2"];
    $from=$row["from"];
    $id=$row["id"];
    $orders =[
    'from' => $from, 
    'where' => $where, 
    'time_min' => $time_min, 
    'time_max' => $time_max, 
    'date1' => $date1, 
    'date2' => $date2, 
    'id' => $id];
    $i++;
    }
}
$data = [ 
'count' =>$i,
'orders' => $orders
];
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $data );
exit;
```

Now the response looks like this:

[image: now]

But I want like this:

[image: want]

Comment: the `mysql_*` api is deprecated / obsolete and has been removed from later versions of PHP. To continue using would seem unwise - especially as your code is vulnerable  potentially to sql injection. Upgrade to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append to the `$orders` array:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders  WHERE id_user = '".$userdata['user_login']."' ORDER BY `nom` ASC ");
    if ($query)
    {
        $i = 0;


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {

    $where=$row["where"];
    $time_min=$row["time_min"];
    $time_max=$row["time_max"];
    $date1=$row["date1"];
    $date2=$row["date2"];
    $from=$row["from"];
    $id=$row["id"];
    $orders[] =[ // <--- The difference
    'from' => $from, 
    'where' => $where, 
    'time_min' => $time_min, 
    'time_max' => $time_max, 
    'date1' => $date1, 
    'date2' => $date2, 
    'id' => $id];
    $i++;
    }
}
$data = [ 
'count' =>$i,
'orders' => $orders
];
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $data );
exit;
```